# Update or delete current row of database results

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to port some old VB6 code to C# and .NET.

There are a number of places where the old code uses a `RecordSet` to execute a SQL query and then loop through the results. No problem so far, but inside the loop the code makes changes to the current row, updating columns and even deleting the current row altogether.

In .NET, I can easily use a `SqlDataReader` to loop through SQL query results, but updates are not supported.

So I've been playing with using a `SqlDataAdapter` to populate a `DataSet`, and then loop through the rows in a `DataSet` table. But the `DataSet` doesn't seem very smart compared to the VB6's old `RecordSet`. For one thing, I need to provide update queries for each type of edit I have. Another concern is that a `DataSet` seems to hold everything in memory at once, which might be a problem if there are many results.

What is the best way to duplicate this behavior in .NET? The code below shows what I have so far. Is this the best approach, or is there another option?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(query, connection)))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataset);

        DataTable table = dataset.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)row["Id"] == 4)
            {
                if ((int)row["Value1"] > 0)
                    row["Value2"] = 12345;
                else
                    row["Value3"] = 12345;
            }
            else if ((int)row["Id"] == 5)
            {
                 row.Delete();
            }
        }

        // TODO:
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("?", connection);
        adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("?", connection);

        adapter.Update(table);
    }
}
```

*Note: I'm new to the company and can't very well tell them they have to change their connection strings or must switch to Entity Framework, which would be my choice. I'm really looking for a code-only solution.*

Comment: What database are you using? If you are using Sql Server you just need to [enable Multiple Active Result Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732642/how-to-enable-multipleactiveresultsets)

Comment: @Steve: SQL Server, but I would've thought this is determined by ADO.NET.

Comment: As above, just use [Multiple Active Result Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars) in your connection string

Comment: Well, I'm new to the company and am not in a position to tell them what connection they must use. Besides, even with that setting, I'm not able to update the current row like the old code. I'd have to run separate queries.

Comment: Yes, you need to execute a separate query. MARS just allow you to use the same connection with two different ops. Another possibility is to open a second connection to update the row but still you need to execute a separate query.

Comment: Or you can use an SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataTable, then loop over the DataTable deleting, updating the rows and finally call the SqlDataAdapter Update method to update everything. Also this has its quirks. You need to SELECT with the primarykey and it doesn't work with joined tables.

Comment: A general solution for this is probably going to be very hard to write. Use the [`DataRow.RowState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property to figure out what rows where deleted and what changed. Another option is to build sql queries instead of updating/deleting the rows, and then run them against the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADO.NET `DataTable` and `DataAdapter` provide the closest equivalent of ADO `Recordset` with applies separation of concens principle. `DataTable` contains the data and provides the change tracking information (similar to EF internal entity tracking) while `DataAdapter` provides a standard way to populate it from database (`Fill` method) and apply changes back to the database (`Update` method).

With that being said, what are you doing is the intended way to port the ADO `Recordset` to ADO.NET. The only thing you've missed is that you are not always required to specify `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` commands. As soon as your query is querying a single table (which I think was a requirement to get updateable `Recordset` anyway), you can use another ADO.NET player called [`DbCommandBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> Automatically generates single-table commands used to reconcile changes made to a `DataSet` with the associated database.

Every database provider provides implementation of this abstract class. The [MSDN example for SqlCommandBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder)%3Bk(vs.objectbrowser)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.1#examples) is almost identical to your sample, so all you need before calling `Update` is (a bit counterintuitive):

```
var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
```

and that's it.

Behind the scenes,

> The `DbCommandBuilder` registers itself as a listener for RowUpdating events that are generated by the DbDataAdapter specified in this property.

and dynamically generates the commands if they are not specifically set in the data adapter by you.

Comment: That seems to do something like my suggestion, only out of the box and with less effort on the user part... The annoying thing is that I knew it exists, I've worked with it before, but forgot all about it... Oh, well, +1 :-)

Comment: This is clearly the definitive answer, in respect to both addressing the core issues of the question and in providing a simple enough solution that I'm convinced this is how Microsoft intended to address what I am trying to do. Initial tests confirm this behaves as expected. The only thing I need to figure out now is how to correctly handle all the `IDisposable` interfaces of `SqlConnection`, `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlCommand`, `DataSet` and `SqlCommandBuilder` without making the code look a mess.

Comment: In general you have to do that. But practically there are only 3 classes in ADO.NET you need to worry about disposing - connection, transaction and reader. With this type of usage - only connection. And in case you are not opening it explicitly (as it looks), not even connection. The `Fill` and `Update` methods will fully handle connection/transaction/reader operations for you similar to the `IQueryable` execution and `SaveChanges` methods of EF `DbContext`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: BTW, you seem to know a lot about this. Could you help me to understand a little bit about memory usage? It seems like `SqlDataReader()` does not load all the results into memory, but that `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` might. Can you confirm?

Comment: @JonathanWood Sure - confirming. The `DataReader` is equivalent of forward only read only database cursor (or `Recordset`). While `DataTable` is equivalent of read only snapshot mode `Recordset` (sorry if I'm not using the right terms, it's been a long time we used VB6 :)) So yes, `DataTable` buffers the whole query. But please note there is no real equivalent of updateable non caching `Recordset` - `DataReader` allows you only to read, and even EF requires the thing to be loaded in order to be able to delete/update it, which leads to load behavior similar to `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an (untested) solution for a data table.
It does require you to do some work, but it should generate update and delete commands for each row you change or delete automatically, by hooking up to the `RowChanged` and `RowDeleted` events of the `DataTable`.

Each row will get it's own command, equivalent to `ADODB.RecordSet` update / delete methods.

However, unlike the `ADODB.RecordSet` methods, this class will not change the underling database, but only create the SqlCommands to do it. Of course, you can change it to simply execute them on once they are created, but as I said, I didn't test it so I'll leave that up to you if you want to do it. However, please note I'm not sure how the `RowChanged` event will behave for multiple changes to the same row. Worst case it will be fired for each change in the row.

The class constructor takes three arguments:

1. The instance of the `DataTable` class you are working with.
2. A `Dictionary<string, SqlDbType>` that provides mapping between column names and SqlDataTypes
3. An optional string to represent table name. If omitted, the `TableName` property of the `DataTable` will be used.

Once you have the mapping dictionary, all you have to do is instantiate the `CommandGenerator` class and iterate the rows in the data table just like in the question. From that point forward everything is automated.

Once you completed your iteration, all you have to do is get the sql commands from the `Commands` property, and run them.

```
public class CommandGenerator
{
    private Dictionary<string, SqlDbType> _columnToDbType;
    private string _tableName;
    private List<SqlCommand> _commands;

    public CommandGenerator(DataTable table, Dictionary<string, SqlDbType> columnToDbType, string tableName = null)
    {
        _commands = new List<SqlCommand>();
        _columnToDbType = columnToDbType;
        _tableName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName)) ? tableName : table.TableName;

        table.RowDeleted += table_RowDeleted;
        table.RowChanged += table_RowChanged;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SqlCommand> Commands { get { return _commands; } }

    private void table_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _commands.Add(GenerateDelete(e.Row));
    }

    private void table_RowDeleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _commands.Add(GenerateDelete(e.Row));
    }

    private SqlCommand GenerateUpdate(DataRow row)
    {

        var table = row.Table;
        var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("UPDATE ").Append(_tableName).Append(" SET ");

        var valueColumns = table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Where(c => !table.PrimaryKey.Contains(c));

        AppendColumns(cmd, sb, valueColumns, row);
        sb.Append(" WHERE ");
        AppendColumns(cmd, sb, table.PrimaryKey, row);

        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        return cmd;
    }

    private SqlCommand GenerateDelete(DataRow row)
    {
        var table = row.Table;
        var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("DELETE FROM ").Append(_tableName).Append(" WHERE ");
        AppendColumns(cmd, sb, table.PrimaryKey, row);
        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        return cmd;
    }

    private void AppendColumns(SqlCommand cmd, StringBuilder sb, IEnumerable<DataColumn> columns, DataRow row)
    {
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            sb.Append(column.ColumnName).Append(" = @").AppendLine(column.ColumnName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + column.ColumnName, _columnToDbType[column.ColumnName]).Value = row[column];
        }
    }
}
```

As I wrote, this is completely untested, but I think it should be enough to at least show the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Your constraints:**

- Not using Entity Framework
- DataSet seems to hold everything in memory at once, which might be a
  problem if there are many results.
- a code-only solution ( no external libraries)

**Plus**

- The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216
  row [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx#Anchor_9)
- To get high performance

  ```
  //the main class to update/delete sql batches without using DataSet/DataTable.


  public class SqlBatchUpdate
      {
          string ConnectionString { get; set; }
          public SqlBatchUpdate(string connstring)
          {
              ConnectionString = connstring;
          }

          public int RunSql(string sql)
          {
              using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
              using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
              {
                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  con.Open();
                  int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  return rowsAffected;
              }
          }
      }

  //------------------------
  // using the class to run a predefined patches

   public class SqlBatchUpdateDemo
      {       
         private string connstring = "myconnstring";

         //run batches in sequence
      public void RunBatchesInSequence()
      {
          var sqlBatchUpdate = new SqlBatchUpdate(connstring);

          //batch1
          var sql1 = @"update mytable set value2 =1234 where id =4  and Value1>0;";
          var nrows = sqlBatchUpdate.RunSql(sql1);
          Console.WriteLine("batch1: {0}", nrows);

          //batch2
          var sql2 = @"update mytable set value3 =1234 where      id =4   and Value1 =0";
            nrows = sqlBatchUpdate.RunSql(sql2);
          Console.WriteLine("batch2: {0}", nrows);

          //batch3
          var sql3 = @"delete from  mytable where id =5;";
            nrows = sqlBatchUpdate.RunSql(sql3);
          Console.WriteLine("batch3: {0}", nrows);


      }

          // Alternative: you can run all batches as one 
              public void RunAllBatches()
              {
                  var sqlBatchUpdate = new SqlBatchUpdate(connstring );
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  var sql1 = @"update mytable set value2 =1234 where id =4  and Value1>0;";
                  sb.AppendLine(sql1);

                  //batch2
                  var  sql2 = @"update mytable set value3 =1234 where     id =4   and Value1 =0";
                  sb.AppendLine(sql2);

                  //batch3
                 var sql3 = @"delete from  mytable where  id =5;";
                  sb.AppendLine(sql3);

                  //run all batches
                  var   nrows = c.RunSql(sb.ToString());
                  Console.WriteLine("all patches: {0}", nrows);
              }


      }
  ```

I simulated that solution and it's working fine with a high performance because all updates /delete run as batch.