# Any way to use method in EF Select extension?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have method which returns a ViewModel async:

```
    public async Task<CardUserBindingViewModel> GetCardUserBindingViewModel(int cardId)
    {
            /// ... creditStatus, remainCreditDays
            return await Task.Run(() => new CardUserBindingViewModel
            {
                Id = card.Id,
                SerialNumber = card.SerialNumber,
                PurchaseDate = card.PurchaseDate,
                Cost = card.Cost,
                CreditStatus = creditStatus,
                RemainCreditDays = remainCreditDays.ToString(),
                Profile = null
            });
    }
```

And want to use it as Select expression such as:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CardUserBindingViewModel>> FindByUserId(int userId)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => 
            { 
                return _context.Card
                .Where(c => c.UserAccountId.Equals(userId))
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(async c => await GetCardUserBindingViewModel(c.Id));
            });
    }
```

The error is :

```
    Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<API.Models.CardUserBindingViewModel>>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<API.Models.CardUserBindingViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Is it possible to prevent making the ViewModel again inside Select extension?

Comment: What's with all the `Task.Run`? In both methods, but specifically in the first one... You're not doing any work when creating the new view model, why wrap it in a task? In the second method is suspect too, EF Core has async operators (ie `ToListAsync`) that you should use instead/in combination with

Comment: it's work if i use: ``.Select(async c => await GetCardUserBindingViewModel(c.Id)).Select(x => x.Result);`` let me know if it's work for you, i can added it like answer.

Comment: @Sajid Not worked, new error raised as One or more errors occurred. (There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks but there are more referenced to these two methods

Comment: i think you can use ``Task.WhenAll`` and separate the query in two subquery, like the following code : ``var cards = context.Card.Where(c =>c.UserAccountId.Equals(userId)).AsEnumerable();return await Task.WhenAll(cards.Select(c => GetCardUserBindingViewModel(c.Id)))``

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to @Sajid and @pinkfloydx33, the problem has solved as below.

Removed Task.Run() from below method:

```
public async Task<CardUserBindingViewModel> GetCardUserBindingViewModel(Card card)
{
    var creditRepository = _service.GetRequiredService<ICreditRepository>();

    var remainCreditDays = await creditRepository.GetCreditRemainDaysByCardId(card);

    var creditStatus = remainCreditDays > 0 ?
        "HasActiveCredit" : "Expired";

    return new CardUserBindingViewModel
    {
        Id = card.Id,
        SerialNumber = card.SerialNumber,
        PurchaseDate = card.PurchaseDate,
        Cost = card.Cost,
        CreditStatus = creditStatus,
        RemainCreditDays = remainCreditDays.ToString(),
        Profile = null
    };
}
```

Change FindByUserId() method as below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CardUserBindingViewModel>> FindByUserId(int userId)
{
    return _context.Card
            .Where(c => c.UserAccountId.Equals(userId))
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(async c => await GetCardUserBindingViewModel(c))
            .Select(c => c.Result);
}
```

And finally adding MultipleActiveResultSets=true to DBContext connection string found here [How to enable MultipleActiveResultSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732642/how-to-enable-multipleactiveresultsets).